# raycast : Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined

Tags: three.js

i'm trying to load my .obj & MTL file into threejs and apply simple wall collision using raycaster. The scene has walls and other objects.

- Used pointer control example
- the loading and texturing are in place
  problem is when using raycaster it throws an error "cannot read property visible of undefined" I guess my referencing is bad.

i used scene.children for passing objects in raycaster
here is the code for ray caster and obj loader. please let me know where im going wrong

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'neavik/' );
                mtlLoader.setPath( 'neavik/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'room.mtl', function( materials ) {
                    materials.preload();
                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.setPath( 'neavik/' );
                    objLoader.load( 'room.obj', function ( object ) {

                        object.position.y = - 5;
                        object.scale.x=object.scale.y=object.scale.z=0.05

                        object.traverse( function( child ) { if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            if (child.material.name == "Interior_wall")  {
                                        child.material = innerwall;
                                        child.castShadow = true;
                                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                                    }
                                    if (child.material.name == "Loby")  {
                                        child.material = innerwall1;
                                        child.castShadow = true;
                                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                                    }
                                    if (child.material.name == "TV_Black_Plastic")  {
                                        child.material = Black;
                                        child.castShadow = true;
                                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                                    }});
                                    object.name = "object";
                                    scene.add( object );
                });

        } );
```

//Raycast

```
var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster(controls.getObject().position, cameraDirection);    
    var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(scene.children, true);   //getting error on this line

    $("#status").html("camera direction x: " + cameraDirection.x + " , z: " + cameraDirection.z);
```

// rest of the code

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code yourself. Use the non-minified version `three.js`, and step through with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and in my case the reason was that the object to be intersected was not existing yet or found at time of intersection.

Therefore I added a kind of null check to prevent this error message:

```
if (typeof scene != "undefined")
```